# Feature request: Mark question as answered even when no answers

Tags: feature-request

A typical question which should not have been asked, but asked, and has some useful content is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693950/setstate-not-triggering-render-call-from-settimeout

In the above question, the piece of code should work. It does work. The question author realizes it after a comment.

Instead of downvoting the question or deleting the question, we should provide a  "Answered" feature which will move the question from the unanswered queue.

The question author can answer the question after two days, and mark it as answer. The delay is a bit too long! Instead, we should allow the question to be "answered" without any answer.

Comment: _"The question author can answer the question after two days"_ The OP can answer the question immediately, marking as answer takes a delay.

Comment: ^ This question just got answered in it's comments.

Comment: " we should allow the question to be "answered" without any answer." Can you explain what this means? It either has an answer or it doesn't. If it doesn't have an answer it cannot be "answered". Note: A comment is not an answer, it is a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the above question, the piece of code should work. It does work. The question author realizes it after a comment.

In which case the question should be closed with the following reason (which it now is):

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

It doesn't have to be answered.

> Instead of downvoting the question or deleting the question

Why would anyone not delete such a question? Such a question is not going to help anyone else. It's a one-off mistake by the author. It doesn't need to stick around. The site is better off without it so users can focus on questions that actually matter. In fact, I'd wager most people who ask questions that turn out to be a dud on their part would agree and be happy to delete the questions themselves.

More to your point, a question without answers cannot be "answered". That's an oxymoron. Either a question is answered or it is not. (Unless your name is Schrödinger, which evidently isn't the case.)

Comment: I agree. Can the question author close it that way? Sometimes, the link is shared in twitter for others to respond.